# Count recurrent words in two files

Tags: java, word-count

I have a code, which can count word occurences in a file. I would like to use this with 2 files and display recurrent(which both files contains) words in a separated table. What is your idea, how is it possible to use it with 2 files?

```
    while ((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] words = inputLine.split("[ \n\t\r.,;:!?(){}]");

        for (int counter = 0; counter < words.length; counter++) {
            String key = words[counter].toLowerCase();
            if (key.length() > 0) {
                if (crunchifyMap.get(key) == null) {
                    crunchifyMap.put(key, 1);
                } else {
                    int value = crunchifyMap.get(key).intValue();
                    value++;
                    crunchifyMap.put(key, value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Set<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> entrySet = crunchifyMap.entrySet();
    System.out.println("Words" + "\t\t" + "# of Occurances");
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : entrySet) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "\t\t" + entry.getValue());
    }
```

Comment: If you just need words that appear in both, you could put the words in each to a `Set`, and then get the common words with `retainAll()`.

Comment: You can try `Set#retainAll()` to find set intersection (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#retainAll-java.util.Collection-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably use the following (very coarse) algorithm:

1. Read the first file and store all words in a `Set words`;
2. Read the second file and store all words in a `Set words2`;
3. Compute the intersecting set by retaining all words in `words` that are also contained in `words2`: [`words.retainAll(words2)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection))
4. `words` contains your final list.

Note that you can reuse the file-reading algorithm if you put it into a method like

```
public Set<String> readWords(Reader reader) {
    ....
}
```

**Count frequency of occurence**

If you also want to know the frequency of occurence, you should read each file into a `Map<String, Integer>` which maps each word to its frequency of occurence within that file.

The new [`Map.merge(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) function (since Java 8) simplifies counting:

```
Map<String, Integer> freq = new HashMap<>();
for(String word : words) {
    // insert 1 or increment already mapped value
    freq.merge(word, 1, Integer::sum);
}
```

Then apply the following, slightly modified algorithm:

1. Read the first file and store all words in a `Map wordsFreq1`;
2. Read the second file and store all words in a `Map wordsFreq2`;
3. Extract the words from the first map: `Set<String> words = wordsFreq1.keySet()`
4. Compute the intersection by retaining all words from the second map: `words.retainAll(wordsFreq2.keySet())`
5. Now `words` contains all the words in common, and `wordsFreq1` and `wordsFreq2` the frequencies of all words of both files.

With these three data structures, you can easily get all information you want. Example:

```
    Map<String, Integer> wordsFreq1 = ... // read from file
    Map<String, Integer> wordsFreq2 = ... // read from file

    Set<String> commonWords = new HashSet<>(wordsFreq1.keySet());
    commonWords.retainAll(wordsFreq2.keySet());

    // Map that contains the summarized frequencies of all words
    Map<String, Integer> allWordsTotalFreq = new HashMap<>(wordsFreq1);
    wordsFreq2.forEach((word, freq) -> allWordsTotalFreq.merge(word, freq, Integer::sum));

    // Map that contains the summarized frequencies of words in common
    Map<String, Integer> commonWordsTotalFreq = new HashMap<>(allWordsTotalFreq);
    commonWordsTotalFreq.keySet().retainAll(commonWords);

    // List of common words sorted by frequency:
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(commonWords);
    Collections.sort(list, Comparator.comparingInt(commonWordsTotalFreq::get).reversed());
```

Comment: Can I count also number of occurences with this method?

Comment: You can count the number of words that occur in both words (`words.size()`), but not how often they occur in both files.

Comment: Is there any way to add also this function to it?

Answer (score 0):

Use similar code to read the second file and find it in the map of the previous file:

```
while ((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] words = inputLine.split("[ \n\t\r.,;:!?(){}]");

    for (int counter = 0; counter < words.length; counter++) {
        String key = words[counter].toLowerCase();
        if (key.length() > 0) {
            if (crunchifyMap.get(key) == null) {
                continue;
            } else if(duplicateMap.get(key) == null) {
                duplicateMap.put(key, 1);
            }
        }
    }
}

Set<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> duplicateEntrySet = duplicateMap.entrySet();
System.out.println("Duplicate words:");
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : duplicateEntrySet ) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey()); 
    }
}
```